# Was Cham influenced by the people destroyed in the mabul?

Tags: historical-figures, parashat-noach, mabul, noach-noah-the-man

In Parshat-Noach, was Cham influenced by the bad people G-d destroyed before the mabul (by his actions with his father)?

Answer (score 1):

The Medresh related that Cham and his wife were the only couple, human or animal, to cohabit while on the Tayvah. All of the other "survivors" remained celibate until emerging from the Ark one year from the start of the Mabul.

http://www.torah.org/learning/rabbis-notebook/5762/noach.html

so it seems, not significantly. he cannot control his passions and this is why Noah cursed that he would be a slave. it was actually for his own good.

Comment: Acc to the Gemara in Sanhedrin 108 it wasn't just cham,it was Cham,the dog ,and the raven